# Getting the latest 10 registered users - Spring security Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I need to get the last 10 registered users (normal users) in my application for statistics. The application has two roles: normal user and administrator user.

In my User class (Spring security), I have the **dateCreated** field and I can obtain the last 10 registered users in my controller with this query:

```
User.listOrderByDateCreated(max: 10, order: 'desc')
```

But I just want to get it between normal users, excluding administrator. With this query, I can obtain all normal users:

```
UserRole.findAllByRole(role).user
```

What query have I to run? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly this is a tricky one, because User doesn't have a direct handle on Role, so the GORM helpers don't help as much. Using straight Groovy list manipulation we can get what you want.

```
def users = User.list().findAll { it.authorities.contains role }
.sort { it.dateCreated }
.reverse()
.take(10)

//or…

def users = UserRole.findAllByRole(role).user
.sort { it.dateCreated }
.reverse()
.take(10)
```

However, if you have a large number of users this would be an inefficient way to get 10 of them. A better option may be to use Hibernate criteria:

```
def users =  UserRole.createCriteria().list(max: 2) { 
  eq "role", role
  user { 
    order 'dateCreated', 'desc'
  }
  projections { property 'user' } 
}
```

Or if you want, you can query using HQL via `executeQuery()`:

```
def users = User.executeQuery("from User where id in (select user.id from UserRole where role.id = :roleId) order by dateCreated desc", [roleId: role.id], [max: 10])
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works!! Although the criteria does not work me. First user and order symbols don't recognize.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a `user` variable in scope somewhere above your criteria (i.e, anything with `def user = ...`). I was hitting my head over that one last night. :)

Comment: Now, it works. The problem was in "eq "role", role". Now, both (criteria and HQL) work. What is the best method in terms of performance, safety, etc.?

Comment: HQL will likely be the most performant, followed by criteria. The Groovy list version is slowest because the call to `User.list()` retrieves *all* users from the database, which is kind of wasteful for 10 users. :)

Comment: Also, if this answer helped you, please consider accepting it so the question shows as "answered". :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> User.executeQuery( "from User user where user.id in (select  userRole.user.id from UserRole userRole where userRole.role.id =:roleId) order by dateCreated desc", [roleId: role.id], [max: 10])
```

Other way is

```
UserRole.executeQuery( "select ur.user from UserRole ur where ur.role.id =:roleId) order by ur.user.dateCreated desc", [roleId: role.id], [max: 10])
```

Let me know if it works for you .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
User.findAllByRole(role,
                 [max: 10, sort: "dateCreated", order: "desc"])
```

Comment: This query does not work because Role is not a field of User. With the first query  I can obtain all normal users (excluding admins). But this list is not filtered (max:10 and sort: dateCreated).